# Attach custom container to the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter

I have a RegisterScreen and i have an image as a Background and over said image i want a container with a glassmorphism effect but my custom GlassmorphismContainer widget won't attach to the bottom of the screen

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/rainforest_Placeholder.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: GlassmorphismContainer(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 350),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class GlassmorphismContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Widget? child;

  const GlassmorphismContainer(
      {super.key, required this.width, required this.height, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (child == null) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          ),
          Center(
            child: ClipRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade600.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        ),
        Center(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
              child: Container(
                width: width,
                height: height,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade600.withOpacity(0.5)),
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have already tried with column and MainAxisAlignment.end and the above method with a Stack and an Align

Comment: please attach img

Comment: Move your asset folder to your root directory. Flutter suggests it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I did not understand wrong, to a achieve such a behaviour, you can use column and mainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween with an SizedBox:

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/rainforest_Placeholder.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          GlassmorphismContainer(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 350),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also in your custom Glassmorphism class, ConstrainedBox throw an error. should care and may consider use another widget.

Comment: Thank u it was actually the ConstrainedBox; after removing it from my custom Container it worked as intended

Answer (score 0):

you're using the `Align` widget to position the `GlassmorphismContainer` at the bottom center of the screen. Instead, you should use the `Positioned` widget.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: GlassmorphismContainer(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 350,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

You can set the `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` positions of your screen as your wish.